# Chamar Partial com IEnumerable dentro de uma página que tem a sua IEnumerable asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

No meu layout tenho uma opção onde mostro algumas notificações, para isso incluir no layout uma partial :

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialNotificacoes")
@model IEnumerable<Generico.Dominio.TB_NOTIFICACAO>     

@if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <a href="Home/LerNotificacao/@item.IDNOTIFICACAO">
            <!--lista de notificações-->
            <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> @Html.DisplayFor(c => item.DESCRICAO);
        </a>
    }
}
```

O problema ocorre quando e chamado uma nova página de listagem porque ela também vai ter o seu próprio IEnumerable, Exemplo de chamada da página:

```
public ActionResult ListarValorAssinatura()
{
    var tbuscar = new ValorAssinaturaAplicacao();
    var listar = tbuscar.ListarTodos();

    var tbuscarNotificacao = new NotificacaoApliacao();
    var retorno = tbuscarNotificacao.ListarTodos();

    if (retorno != null)
    {
        ViewData["QtdNotificacao"] = retorno.Count();
        // ViewData["ListaNotificacao"] = retorno;
    }

    return View(listar);
}
```

Neste ponto estou retornando a lista, mais não estou retornando as notificações,  então tenho um erro:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Generico.Dominio.TB_VALOR_ASSINATURA]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Generico.Dominio.TB_NOTIFICACAO]'.

Opções que já fiz teste:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialNotificacoes")
@Html.Partial("~/BuscarNotificacoes/Home/_PartialNotificacoes.cshtml")
@Html.Action("BuscarNotificacoes", "Home").
```

Comment: você quer retonar duas lista uma seria a pagina que carrega e dentro dela um partialView também carrega a outra lista?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, sim,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça uma classe que vai representar o resultado das duas coleções:

```
public class ViewModelHome
{
    public List<Generico.Dominio.TB_NOTIFICACAO> Notificacoes { get; set; }
    public List<Generico.Dominio.TB_VALOR_ASSINATURA> Assinaturas { get; set; }
}
```

na `ActionResult`, crie um objeto dessa classe `ViewModelHome` e passe os valores correspondentes para as suas propriedades (`Notificacoes` e `Assinaturas`)

```
public ActionResult ListarValorAssinatura()
{
    var viewModelHome = new ViewModelHome();

    var tbuscar = new ValorAssinaturaAplicacao();
    viewModelHome.Assinaturas = tbuscar.ListarTodos();

    var tbuscarNotificacao = new NotificacaoApliacao();
    viewModelHome.Notificacoes = tbuscarNotificacao.ListarTodos();

    return View(viewModelHome);
}
```

na `View` principal mude o `model` para aquele que agora está sendo enviado para `View`

```
@model ViewModelHome
```

a variável `Model` terá as duas lista como propriedades e para passar isso na `PartialView`

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialNotificacoes", Model.Notificacoes)
```

o `foreach` da principal é algo assim:

```
foreach (var item in Model.Assinaturas)
{
    //.......
}
```

<sub>**Observação**: os nomes podem ser a seu critério, isso é apenas para ilustrar a sua duvida.</sub>

Comment: Estou muito agradecido pela ajuda